# Azure Logic App Integration to the application

Tags: azure, integration, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I created a logic app in Azure Portal,
now I want to integrate the logic app into the application which we are developing,
I don't know the exact requirements to integrate the logic app into the application
can anyone explain how to integrate the logic app into my application using .Net
if you know any code samples can you please share it to me.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean trigger the logic app in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Logic apps support http webhook trigger to invoke rest api.

[image]

[Logic App Webhook Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook)